# Personalize checkout text

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to hide some of the text in the checkout page: billing details, Order notes (optional) and product/total row in "your order" section.

I am able to remove the input fields, but I cant find a way to remove the text. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the WooCommerce docs, you'll see that you can override template parts by having a replacement file in a `woocommerce` folder in your theme.  A lot of the text you're talking about is hardcoded into `woocommerce > templates > checkout > review-order.php`  Copy that file and modify as needed.  Normally I would advocate for trying to use filters instead of duping the template file but I think there's going to be a few things you will have to do in that template file to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking to use filters instead, but overriding templates worked just fine for me.